# Excluding "provided" scope dependencies during "test" execution phase?

Tags: maven, maven-3

I'm seeing a jar with `provided` scope in my classpath during test execution. Given the definition of the `provided` scope, I would not expect that jar to appear on the classpath during any execution phase.

I've confirmed that the scope is correct using the M2E "Dependency Hierarchy" view. I've already tried using the `classpathDependencyScopeExclude` option in `maven-surefire-plugin` to keep the dependency from showing up, and it hasn't worked:

```
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <!--
            We always want to exclude provided deps. I'm not sure why this
            isn't the default.
          -->
          <classpathDependencyScopeExclude>provided</classpathDependencyScopeExclude>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Here is the dependency definition in question:

**Parent POM**:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**Module POM**:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Is it normal that the jar is there? What can I do to keep it from showing up?

**EDIT**: I've run `mvn dependency:tree` on the parent POM. Here's the output for the project in question:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building sibyl.transport.impl.http.server 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ sibyl.transport.impl.http.server ---
[INFO] com.sigpwned.analytics:sibyl.transport.impl.http.server:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.sigpwned.analytics:sibyl.transport:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- com.sigpwned.analytics:commons:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.1.1:provided
[INFO] +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.17.1:test (scope not updated to compile)
[INFO] |  +- asm:asm:jar:3.1:test
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.17.1:test
[INFO] +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-servlet:jar:1.17.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:9.0.3.v20130506:test
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:9.0.3.v20130506:test
[INFO] |     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.0.3.v20130506:test
[INFO] |        +- org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.servlet:jar:3.0.0.v201112011016:test
[INFO] |        +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.0.3.v20130506:test
[INFO] |        |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.0.3.v20130506:test
[INFO] |        \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.0.3.v20130506:test
[INFO] +- com.sigpwned.analytics:sibyl.transport.impl.http.client:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:test
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.2.5:test
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.2.4:test
[INFO] |     +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:test
[INFO] |     \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.6:test
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[INFO]    \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
```

Again, the jar with provided scope that I expect not to show up on the classpath but does is the JAX-RS spec API, shown above as `javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.1.1:provided`. I believe this confirms that this dependency only appears in the `provided` scope.

**EDIT**: If I run the test, here is the command line that gets run (from `ps`):

```
sigpwned       11771   0.0  1.2  4019788 100240   ??  S    10:58PM   0:05.92 /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_21.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,suspend=y,address=localhost:59974 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Users/aboothe/Documents/workspaces/w2oanalytics/sibyl.transport.impl.http.server/target/test-classes:/Users/aboothe/Documents/workspaces/w2oanalytics/sibyl.transport.impl.http.server/target/classes:/Users/aboothe/Documents/workspaces/w2oanalytics/sibyl/sibyl.transport/target/classes:/Users/aboothe/Documents/workspaces/w2oanalytics/commons/target/classes:/Users/aboothe/.m2/repository/javax/ws/rs/jsr311-api/1.1.1/jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar:/Users/aboothe/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-server/1.17.1/jersey-server-1.17.1.jar:/Users/aboothe/.m2/repository/asm/asm/3.1/asm-3.1.jar:/Users/aboothe/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-core/1.17.1/jersey-core-1.17.1.jar:/Users/aboothe/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-servlet/1.17.1/jersey-servlet-1.17.1.jar:/Users/aboothe/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-servlet/9.0.3.v20130506/jetty-servlet-9.0.3.v20130506.jar:/Users/aboothe/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-security/9.0.3.v20130506/jetty-security-9.0.3.v20130506.jar:/Users/aboothe/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-server/9.0.3.v20130506/jetty-server-9.0.3.v20130506.jar:/Users/aboothe/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/orbit/javax.servlet/3.0.0.v201112011016/javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar:/Users/aboothe/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-http/9.0.3.v20130506/jetty-http-9.0.3.v20130506.jar:/Users/aboothe/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-util/9.0.3.v20130506/jetty-util-9.0.3.v20130506.jar:/Users/aboothe/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-io/9.0.3.v20130506/jetty-io-9.0.3.v20130506.jar:/Users/aboothe/Documents/workspaces/w2oanalytics/sibyl.transport.impl.http.client/target/classes:/Users/aboothe/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.2.5/httpclient-4.2.5.jar:/Users/aboothe/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.2.4/httpcore-4.2.4.jar:/Users/aboothe/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/Users/aboothe/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.6/commons-codec-1.6.jar:/Users/aboothe/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.11/junit-4.11.jar:/Users/aboothe/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/Users/aboothe/Downloads/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/350/1/.cp/:/Users/aboothe/Downloads/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/349/1/.cp/ org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner -version 3 -port 59973 -testLoaderClass org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader -loaderpluginname org.eclipse.jdt.junit4.runtime -classNames com.sigpwned.analytics.sibyl.transport.impl.http.server.HttpServerTransportTests
```

If you pull out the classpath, here's what that looks like:

```
/Users/sigpwned/Documents/workspaces/siganalytics/sibyl.transport.impl.http.server/target/test-classes
/Users/sigpwned/Documents/workspaces/siganalytics/sibyl.transport.impl.http.server/target/classes
/Users/sigpwned/Documents/workspaces/siganalytics/sibyl/sibyl.transport/target/classes
/Users/sigpwned/Documents/workspaces/siganalytics/commons/target/classes
/Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/javax/ws/rs/jsr311-api/1.1.1/jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar
/Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-server/1.17.1/jersey-server-1.17.1.jar
/Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/asm/asm/3.1/asm-3.1.jar
/Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-core/1.17.1/jersey-core-1.17.1.jar
/Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-servlet/1.17.1/jersey-servlet-1.17.1.jar
/Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-servlet/9.0.3.v20130506/jetty-servlet-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
/Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-security/9.0.3.v20130506/jetty-security-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
/Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-server/9.0.3.v20130506/jetty-server-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
/Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/orbit/javax.servlet/3.0.0.v201112011016/javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar
/Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-http/9.0.3.v20130506/jetty-http-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
/Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-util/9.0.3.v20130506/jetty-util-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
/Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-io/9.0.3.v20130506/jetty-io-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
/Users/sigpwned/Documents/workspaces/siganalytics/sibyl.transport.impl.http.client/target/classes
/Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.2.5/httpclient-4.2.5.jar
/Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.2.4/httpcore-4.2.4.jar
/Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
/Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.6/commons-codec-1.6.jar
/Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.11/junit-4.11.jar
/Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
/Users/sigpwned/Downloads/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/350/1/.cp/
/Users/sigpwned/Downloads/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/349/1/.cp/
```

**EDIT**: After investigating the `classpathDependencyScopeExclude` documentation, I determined that you can only exclude `compile`, `runtime`, and `test` dependencies, not `provided`. This explains why that functionality doesn't work. After trying the suggestion from @hello below, I've determined that `classpathDependencyExclude` works when running directly with maven. Here's the classpath that I ripped out of the surefire jar's MANIFEST:

```
  file:/Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-booter/2.14.1/surefire-booter-2.14.1.jar
  file:/Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-api/2.14.1/surefire-api-2.14.1.jar
  file:/Users/sigpwned/Documents/workspaces/siganalytics/sibyl/sibyl.transport.impl.http.server/target/test-classes/
  file:/Users/sigpwned/Documents/workspaces/siganalytics/sibyl/sibyl.transport.impl.http.server/target/classes/
  file:/Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/com/siggroup/analytics/sibyl.transport/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/sibyl.transport-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
  file:/Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/com/siggroup/analytics/commons/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/commons-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
  file:/Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-server/9.0.3.v20130506/jetty-server-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
  file:/Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/orbit/javax.servlet/3.0.0.v201112011016/javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar
  file:/Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-http/9.0.3.v20130506/jetty-http-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
  file:/Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-util/9.0.3.v20130506/jetty-util-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
  file:/Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-io/9.0.3.v20130506/jetty-io-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
  file:/Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-servlet/9.0.3.v20130506/jetty-servlet-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
  file:/Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-security/9.0.3.v20130506/jetty-security-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
  file:/Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-server/1.17.1/jersey-server-1.17.1.jar
  file:/Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/asm/asm/3.1/asm-3.1.jar
  file:/Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-core/1.17.1/jersey-core-1.17.1.jar
  file:/Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-servlet/1.17.1/jersey-servlet-1.17.1.jar
  file:/Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/com/siggroup/analytics/sibyl.transport.impl.http.client/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/sibyl.transport.impl.http.client-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
  file:/Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.2.4/httpclient-4.2.4.jar
  file:/Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.2.4/httpcore-4.2.4.jar
  file:/Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
  file:/Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.6/commons-codec-1.6.jar
  file:/Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/com/siggroup/analytics/sibyl.transport/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/sibyl.transport-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar
  file:/Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.11/junit-4.11.jar
  file:/Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
```

Notice that jsr311-api.jar is not present. Success! Here's the configuration that worked:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
  <configuration>
    <!--
      We never want to include these API deps on an execution classpath.
      I would think this is how the "provided" scope works - just
      compile against the jar, and then I'll bring it myself at
      execution time - but provided is only excluded during the runtime
      phase, not the testing phase. So, we have to exclude all our
      API JARs by hand.
    -->
    <classpathDependencyExcludes>
      <classpathDependencyExclude>javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api</classpathDependencyExclude>
    </classpathDependencyExcludes>
    <includes>
      <include>**/*Tests.*</include>
    </includes>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

However, this solution does *not* seem to work on M2E. Here's the classpath I've pulled out from a `ps` during test execution using M2E:

```
  /Users/sigpwned/Documents/workspaces/siganalytics/sibyl/sibyl.transport.impl.http.server/target/test-classes
  /Users/sigpwned/Documents/workspaces/siganalytics/sibyl/sibyl.transport.impl.http.server/target/classes
  /Users/sigpwned/Documents/workspaces/siganalytics/sibyl/sibyl.transport/target/classes
  /Users/sigpwned/Documents/workspaces/siganalytics/commons/target/classes
> /Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/javax/ws/rs/jsr311-api/1.1.1/jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar
  /Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-server/9.0.3.v20130506/jetty-server-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
  /Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/orbit/javax.servlet/3.0.0.v201112011016/javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar
  /Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-http/9.0.3.v20130506/jetty-http-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
  /Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-util/9.0.3.v20130506/jetty-util-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
  /Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-io/9.0.3.v20130506/jetty-io-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
  /Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-servlet/9.0.3.v20130506/jetty-servlet-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
  /Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-security/9.0.3.v20130506/jetty-security-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
  /Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-server/1.17.1/jersey-server-1.17.1.jar
  /Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/asm/asm/3.1/asm-3.1.jar
  /Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-core/1.17.1/jersey-core-1.17.1.jar
  /Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-servlet/1.17.1/jersey-servlet-1.17.1.jar
  /Users/sigpwned/Documents/workspaces/siganalytics/sibyl/sibyl.transport.impl.http.client/target/classes
  /Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.2.4/httpclient-4.2.4.jar
  /Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.2.4/httpcore-4.2.4.jar
  /Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
  /Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.6/commons-codec-1.6.jar
  /Users/sigpwned/Documents/workspaces/siganalytics/sibyl/sibyl.transport/target/test-classes
  /Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.11/junit-4.11.jar
  /Users/sigpwned/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
  /Users/sigpwned/Downloads/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/350/1/.cp/
  /Users/sigpwned/Downloads/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/349/1/.cp/
```

Unfortunately, jsr311-api.jar is still there. This leads me to believe that this question is answered (with that answer being "use `classpathDependencyExcludes`"), but there's a bug in M2E. I ran "Check for Updates" in Eclipse and found no update for M2E, so I should be running the latest stable release. I'll file a bug on M2E and update with the issue here so anyone who finds this issue can track.

**EDIT**: This issue was [already raised](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=406486) with M2E, and the answer appears to be "Surefire integration is outside the scope of M2E at this time." Not encouraging. :/

Comment: Maybe the dependency is included elsewhere as a runtime dependency, or maybe something else is importing the same library. Have you tried running the dependency tree command and searching for the artifact name within it?

Comment: @EngineerDollery I don't believe that's the case. I've added some additional information to the question that explain why. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: @sigpwned Why don't you post your valuable edits as an answer and accept it? To me they look like a solution to the problem instead of the currently accepted answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Given the definition of the `provided` scope, I would not expect that jar to appear on the classpath during any execution phase.

This is not quite the behaviour of `provided` scope; see [Dependency Scope](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope). `provided` scope, in common with `compile`, is for classes that are necessary to compile and test your classes. If they were missing during `test` then you would have a `NoClassDefFoundError`.

The difference comes during packaging and deployment, where these artifacts are omitted from `war`s under the assumption that your target environment (for example, a servlet container) will provide its own copy of the same classes.

Comment: Evidently so! However, how do I indicate to maven that a dependency is for compile only, and should never appear on the classpath during any execution phase (including test)?

Comment: I found that `classpathDependencyScopeExclude` didn't work but [`classpathDependencyExcludes`](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#classpathDependencyExcludes) did:
    <classpathDependencyExcludes>
      <exclude>javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api</exclude>
    </classpathDependencyExcludes>

In general, there's no scope that corresponds to what you're after. You would need to exclude it for each goal.

Comment: That works! (Note that the syntax is `<classpathDependencyExcludes><classpathDependencyExclude>groupId:artifactId</classpathDependencyExclude></classpathDependencyExcludes>`, though.) I've accepted your answer and udpated my question. Thank you!